# Can I place an adjective after the noun it describes, like "My hair is a fast-growing"?

Tags: sentence-construction, word-order

I want to say, I have a type of hair that grows fast like:

My hair is a fast-growing.

where fast-growing is an adjective and the article "a" connect the adjective "fast-growing" with the noun "hair". Is that correct usage?

Answer (score 1):

It is not a correct usage to say: *My hair is a fast-growing* because articles must be followed by nouns either with or without adjectives in between.

You can say **I have fast-growing hair**

or **My hair grows fast/My hair is growing fast**

or just **My hair is fast-growing**

All of the alternatives above don't use the article **a** because the noun **hair** refers to the entire strands of hair on your head.

Let me know if you ever come across this kind of sentence.

Comment: it came out of my head and the first version of it in my head was just like you last example: "just My hair is fast-growing" I added the article because i was "afraid" the "fast-growing" after the noun could sounds like a verb, get it?

Comment: "My hair is a fast-growing" ... interesting. Do you have any source to prove that your assertion is correct here?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).